# Is there a way to recommend a change to a tag name on SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I'm doing some edits on SO and noticing that someone has been doing a lot of correcting for the [hotspot](/questions/tagged/hotspot) tag.  It seems that folks expect "hotspot" to mean a personal hotspot, but the [hotspot](/questions/tagged/hotspot) tag is actually used for "*the standard Java virtual machine used by both the Oracle and OpenJDK Java runtime environments*."  There is a [personal-hotspot](/questions/tagged/personal-hotspot), but it's being missed.

I'd like to suggest that the "hotspot" tag be changed to [hotspot-jvm](/questions/tagged/hotspot-jvm), but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to make this suggestion on the tag edit page:

https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/12598

Should there be a way to do this?  Or is the problem simply that my rep is too low on SO (currently < 3k)?

Comment: You're in the right place right now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, tag renames like this should be done by a moderator. Just come here to Meta and post a question (like you have), so you can get community support for the rename and also flesh out any other problems with the tag.

I've been in the process of going through this tag and retagging all the Wi-Fi Hotspot questions into [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi). I've also encountered a few image hotspot questions, from which I've just been removing the tag. Once all that's done, I'll rename the tag to [jvm-hotspot](/questions/tagged/jvm-hotspot) for you.

**Note:** Creating that synonym is not useful. All that would do is redirect [hotspot-jvm](/questions/tagged/hotspot-jvm) questions to the master [hotspot](/questions/tagged/hotspot) tag, which would mean you'd still have all the same problems.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

You require a minimum of 1500 rep to create a tag. But, don't worry, you've come to the right place to request one!

Also, there's something called tag-synonyms. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms for that.

Comment: I understand that priv, but what I really want to do is change an existing tag name.

Comment: Updated my answer for that. The tag-synonyms do exactly that.